# display count = 0 for id not exists in foreign table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables

**articles_type**

```
id  type
1   article
2   free
3   review
```

**user_fav**

```
uid  article_type_id
1    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
3    3
4    1
4    2
4    3
```

I need to back user with article type if user do not added type then display 0

the expected result

for uid = 1

```
article_type_id   count
1                 1
2                 1
3                 0
------------------------------
```

for uid = 2

```
article_type_id   count
1                 1
2                 0
3                 0
------------------------------
```

for uid = 3

```
article_type_id   count
1                 0
2                 1
3                 1
------------------------------
```

for uid = 4

```
article_type_id   count
1                 1
2                 1
3                 1
```

I have tried the following query to get the expected result.

**QUERY:**

```
select article_type_id, count (article_type_id)
from article_types
left join user_fav on user_fav.article_type_id = article_type.id
where uid = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the condition is in the second table of a `left join`, then you need to include it the `on` clause.  Also, your query needs a `group by`:

The query you want is:

```
select a.article_type_id, count(*)
from article_types a left join
     user_fav u
     on u.article_type_id = a.id and u.uid = 1
group by a.article_type_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select article_type_id, coalesce(count(article_type_id),0)
from article_types
left join user_fav on user_fav.article_type_id = article_type.id
where uid = 1
```